# How to configure webpack dev server to serve extensionless files as 'text/html'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

### Problem

In development, serving files without an extension (e.g. /region) are being served with mimetype `application/octet-stream'.  Desired state is to serve these with mimetype 'text/html'.

### Context

Writing a multipage application using Vue3.  Upgraded @vue/cli and that upgraded webpack from 4 to 5. Serving extensionless files did not have this issue using webpack4's dev server.

In production this isn't a problem as the webserver there is configured to serve these files with the 'text/html' mimetype.

#### Dependency versions

node 16.13.0, webpack 5.64.1, webpack-dev-middleware 5.2.1, @vue/cli 5.0.0-rc.0

#### Webpack5 config

```js
  entry: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    region: [                                                                                                                               
      '/home/alice/workspace/vapp/src/pages/region/main.js'                                                                              
    ], 
  plugins: [
    /* config.plugin('html-region') */                                                                                                      
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(                                                                                                                  
      {                                                                                                                                     
        title: 'Region',                                                                                                              
        scriptLoading: 'defer',                                                                                                             
        templateParameters: function () { /* omitted long function */ },                                                                    
        chunks: [                                                                                                                           
          'chunk-vendors',                                                                                                                  
          'chunk-common',                                                                                                                   
          'region'                                                                                                                          
        ],                                                                                                                                  
        template: 'src/pages/region/region.html',                                                                                           
        filename: 'region'                                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                                                                     
    ), 
  ]
```

### Attempts

Supplying custom extension to mime type mapping works for custom extensions just fine, e.g. `'foo': 'text/html'` will serve region.foo as html.  However, there doesn't appear to be a way to specify a mime type for files without an extension.  None of the these mimeTypes entries have been successful.

```js
  // webpack.config.js
  devServer: {                                                                                                                              
    devMiddleware: {                                                                                                                        
      mimeTypes: {                                                                                                                          
        '': 'text/html',                                                                                                                    
        false: 'text/html',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        null: 'text/html',
        default: 'text/html',                                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                       
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mimeTypeDefault` option of [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware).

If you're using `webpack-dev-server` instead of `webpack-dev-middleware` directly, then use this in your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        devMiddleware: {
            mimeTypeDefault: 'text/html'
        },
    },
};
```

At the time of writing this only works with the `webpack-dev-middleware` 6.x, which `webpack-dev-server` hasn't been updated to use yet, so you will also need to forcibly update the `webpack-dev-middleware` to the latest version (the only breaking changes are in minimum webpack and node versions, so this is safe). To do this add this to your `package.json`:

```json
  "overrides": {
    "webpack-dev-server": {
      "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.1.1"
    }
  }
```

I'm sure `webpack-dev-server` will be updated to use the latest middleware version soon, after which the override won't be necessary.